# how to show a modulate signal in Matlab simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

i want to show the signal modulate in simulink but i don't know how to make it
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Spectrum Scope calculates the FFT of the input signal.
In your model you are trying to take the fft of the fft.
(Although you aren't quite doing that as the input to the FFT block needs to be buffered so that the FFT has a vector of data over which to calculate the FFT.)

Remove your FFT and Abs blocks and feed the signal directly into the Spectrum Scope.
Use the block's dialog to set the buffer and FFT length that you want to use.

Phil.